# MSCOMCTL.OCX missing on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: vba, windows-server-2008-r2

Migrating a legacy Visual Basic application from Windows 2000 to Windows 2008 R2, I get the error

> Component 'MSCOMCTL.OCX' or one of its dependencies not correctly
>   registered: a file is missing or invalid

Installing VisualBasic6-KB896559-v1-ENU.exe didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason MSCOMCTL.OCX didn't get copied / registered to the correct folder when installing the downloaded runtime `VisualBasic6-KB896559-v1-ENU.exe` from the KB896559 at https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=10019.

These manual steps fixed it:

1. Use 7-Zip to unpack VisualBasic6-KB896559-v1-ENU.exe (NB: executing this file won't install anything!)
2. Copy the contents to %systemroot%\SysWow64
3. From command line (run `cmd` as administrator), execute

   %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe %systemroot%\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx
4. Try running your archaic Visual Basic app again!

Comment: I believe the most recent version of mscomctl.ocx (6.1.98.46) is included in VB60SP6-KB3096896-x86-ENU.msi  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50722  Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Security Rollup Update 1/8/2016