# Install MSCOMCTL.OCX 2.1 on a naked system

Tags: windows, vb6, windows-8.1, common-controls

How to install programmatically a current version of `mscomctl.ocx` on a Windows 8.1 system, so that version 2.1 of the type library is registered? Installing the ancient ["Common controls" download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10019) only installs version 2.0. I think I need  the update related to [MS12-060](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms12-060.aspx), which would be now [KB2726929](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36010), but this update doesn't install when MS Office is not installed.

[A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13948897/946850) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11982719/946850) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25634767/946850) questions are related, but they mostly deal with the effects of the updates mentioned above. I'd like to build a system where I can compile VB6 projects that refer to version 2.1 of the `mscomctl.ocx` type library.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the file from a machine that has the update installed?  Use Regsvr32.exe to register it.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was hoping for a more "official" way -- as a last resort, your suggestion surely will work.

Comment: Have you checked http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10019 yet?

Comment: Oops, sorry.  That package only has one with the 2.0 interfaces defined.

Comment: Even if you "steal it" (it seems to be considered part of Office) from another mchine you might consider http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597986

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest cumulative roll-up components for VB6 - this one is included in the list.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957924

Comment: This only updates the file if it was already installed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634767/mscomctl-ocx-missing-on-windows-2008-r2

Comment: The person asking the question already stated that he is looking to upgrade to "a current version" - so the link doing the upgrade will be exactly what he would need.
Alternatively - you can always unpack the patch (e.g. by using 7-ZIP) and copy the files (to C:\Windows\SysWOW64) and manually register them (by running C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 <dll-name.dll> )